# network ID error while deploying a truffle project to ganache cli. how do i resolve it

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, truffle-migration, ganache-cli

when I deploy my truffle project to ganache I get the error, network id are not the same. and when I checked the network id on ganache and truffle, i changed the network id of truffle to match that of ganache but it is still giving me the same error on my terminal. how do i solve this problem. thank you.

Comment: Can you share your truffle-cofig.js file so we might see what an issue is? Example: https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration/